# Sailsjs: Model is not inserting record on calling create method

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I have a model `Sample`, When I try to to insert a record to this model `Sample.create(req.body, res.send({done: 1}));` or `Sample.create(req.body).exec(res.send({done: 1}));`I am not seeing any records beeing inserted on `get` request. I am executing this operation in `SampleController.create` I am getting response as `{done: 1}` without new record being inserted. As per sailsjs documentation, we can use `Sample.save()` but I am always getting exception no such method.

Note: `Sample` has only one field `firstName`. Using sailsjs 0.9.9

So what's wrong going here in order to insert new record?

Comment: Run `Sample.create(req.body).done(err, sample){if (err) console.log(err); else console.log(sample);};`. What's the output?

Comment: @bnuhero Thank you, this is throwing error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`, just now I could solve the problem, it is working fine in this way `Sample.create(req.body, function(err, sample) {res.send(sample)})`.

Comment: Fixed it: Sample.create(req.body).done(function(err, sample){if (err) console.log(err); else console.log(sample);});. It should work now. See: model.md. BTW, the latest stable release of Sails is v0.9.13.

Answer (score 2):

You're not calling `Model.create` correctly.  The signature is either:

```
Model.create(data, callback)
```

or, better:

```
Model.create(data).exec(callback)
```

Where callback is a function with arguments `err` and `createdModel`.  All together:

```
Sample.create(req.body).exec(function(err, sample) {

    if (err) {return res.serverError(err);}
    res.json(sample);

});
```

Docs are on the [Sails website](http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models) or on [Github](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/models.md#create).